# How to install GCC 5.4 on ubuntu 17.10 (Downgrade)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

I have ubuntu 17.10. 
gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2)

I have to get GCC 5.4. I've tried:

```
 sudo apt-get install gcc-5.4

 sudo apt-get install gcc-5.4 g++-5.4
```

But i'm receiving :

```
E: Unable to locate package gcc-5.4
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gcc-5.4'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-5.4'
```

At `apt-get install gcc` I receive 
    gcc is already the newest version (4:7.2.0-1ubuntu1).

I have to downgrade to 5.4,

How can I solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to the [packages.ubuntu.com page for gcc-5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gcc-5) and you will see that eg xenial still has it: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gcc-5

Now it may just be a matter of adding the xenial repo info back into `/etc/sources.list` (or maybe `/etc/sources.list.d/xenial.conf` to easily uncomment later), run `apt-get update` and `apt-get install gcc-5`.

Another alternative is to use Docker and just run in a xenial container...

Comment: what do I do with these lists?
Could you elaborate?

Answer (score -2):

I work it

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/gcc-5/download

in

> /etc/apt/sources.list
>
> deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe